# Different event on different projects

Tags: spring-boot, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I have the same jar deployed on 2 different projects. The project have 2 entities (Account and Buyer) the Account has a list of Buyers a Buyer has an Account. When I change the Account of a Buyer I need to remove the Buyer from one List<Buyer> and add on another List<Buyer> of Buyer, right? The following code shows this.
But the problem is, on Project-A when I run the code the Buyer keeps on both List and when I run the Project-B the Buyer is removed from old List on Account and added to the new List on Account.
There is a problem with my datastore?

```
// Account class resumed
public class Account implements Serializable {
    ...
    @Reference
    private List<Buyer> buyers = new ArrayList<>();
    ...
}
```

```
//  Account class resumed
public class Buyer implements Serializable {
    ...
    @Reference
    private Account account;
    ...
}
```

```
// The transaction
@Transactional
public void update(Long id, Buyer updatedBuyer) {
    Buyer buyer = find(id);
    Buyer found = repository.findByEmailAndAccount(updatedBuyer.getEmail(), updatedBuyer.getAccount()).orElse(null);
    if (found != null && !found.getId().equals(id)) {
        throw new DataIntegrityException("Comprador já cadastrado");
    }
    accountService.deleteBuyers(buyer.getAccount(), buyer);
    buyer.setEmail(updatedBuyer.getEmail());
    buyer.setTelephone(updatedBuyer.getTelephone());
    buyer.setCreationDate(updatedBuyer.getCreationDate());
    buyer.setExpirationDate(updatedBuyer.getExpirationDate());
    buyer.setAccount(updatedBuyer.getAccount());
    buyer.getAccount().addBuyer(buyer);
    repository.save(buyer);
}
```

```
// The deleteBuyers used above
public void deleteBuyers(Account account, Buyer... buyers) {
    for (Buyer b : buyers) {
        account.getBuyers().remove(b);
    }
    repository.save(account);
}
```

```
// The updatedBuyer came from here
public Buyer fromDTO(PatchBuyerDTO patchBuyerDTO) {
    return new Buyer(patchBuyerDTO.getEmail(), patchBuyerDTO.getTelephone(), false, patchBuyerDTO.getCreationDate(), patchBuyerDTO.getExpirationDate(), accountService.find(patchBuyerDTO.getAccountDTO().getId()));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem was on creation, I wasn't saving account, only buyer

```
// before
return repository.save(buyer)
// after
repository.saveAll(Arrays.asList(buyer));
return buyer;
```